# How can I change error message in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I create a form and then when I click on submit button, show this error message:

> Please select an item in the list.

How can I change this message and style it ( with CSS )?

Entity:

```
...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Hi user, Please select an item")
     */
    private $name;
...
```

Controller:

```
...
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $form = $this->createForm(MagListType::class);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]);
        }
...
```

Form:

```
...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => InsCompareList::class,
                'label' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $rp){
                return $rp->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'OK'
            ])
        ;
...
}
```

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: Not that many Symfony 1.4 developers still around.

Comment: You can apply bootstrap class

Comment: How to change this error whitout Bootstrap class?

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: Can you share the code you already have by editing your question?

Comment: @Helenesh , I edit my question

Comment: My code is wrong?

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use custom messages, you have to put 'novalidate' on your HTML form. For example:

**With Twig:**

```
  {{ form_start(form, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
  {{ form_widget(form) }}
  {{ form_end(form) }}
```

**Or in your controller:**

```
$form = $this->createForm(MagListType::class, $task, array( //where task is your entity instance
    'attr' => array(
           'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
    )
));
```

[This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31434636/4742088) has more info on how to use novalidate with Symfony. You can also check the docs for more info.

As for the styling, you can use JavaScript to trigger classes, which you can then style in your CSS, like in this example taken from [Happier HTML5 Form Validation](https://daverupert.com/2017/11/happier-html5-forms/) . You can also take a look at the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) and play with the `:valid` and `:invalid` selectors.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea");

inputs.forEach(input => {
   input.addEventListener(
      "invalid",
        event => {
          input.classList.add("error");
        },
        false
    );
  });
```

**EDIT:**
You are probably not seeing your custom message because it comes from server side, the message that you're currently seeing when submitting your form is client-side validation. So you can either place `novalidate` on your field, or you can override the validation messages on the client side by using `setCustomValidity(`), as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132204/4742088) which also contains many useful links. An example using your Form Builder:

```
 $builder
    ->add('name', EntityType::class,[
          'class' => InsCompareList::class,
          'label' => false,
          [
           'attr' => [
             'oninvalid' => "setCustomValidity('Hi user, Please select an item')"
           ]
          ],

          'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $rp){
                return $rp->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
                },
              'choice_label' => 'name',
              'choice_value' => 'id',
              'required' => true,
            ])
      ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
          'label' => 'OK'
         ]);
```

Comment: When I use this code " @Assert\NotBlank(message="Hi user, Please select an item") " not work

Comment: I tested this code and it works. Can you share your form builder code?

Comment: When use "novalidate" all validator are disabled

Comment: I add "attr" to my $builder but not work and when click submit button go to action address.

Comment: I think that @Assert\NotBlank(message="Hi user, Please select an item") not work!!!

Comment: I have given all the necessary information regarding Symfony validations. Cannot help you further sorry.